# ScheduledExecutorService doesnt start

Tags: android

I have some Problems with ScheduledExecutorService.
I want to start the notification after some time. In this case its 10 seconds. But after 10 seconds it doesnt start. All functions beyond this working correctly.

Here is the code:

```
 ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
                    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                 scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() { 
                   public void run() { 
                       Toast.makeText(BService.this, "It works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // Display a notification about us starting.  We put an icon in the status bar.
                        showNotification();
                    } 
                  }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Thanks for help
Roa

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem and I found out why.
The run() is not being called on the UI thread and the Toast crashes that thread (but for some unknown reason it does not give anything on the LogCat).

But if you do:

```
task.schedule(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        // your Toas goes in here
        }
    });
    }
}, DURATION, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

it will work!

Answer (score 0):

`ScheduledExecutorService.schedule()` is called correctly, so I guess that your `run()` does wrong for some reason. You may **add a log at begin of `run()`** to check it starts or not.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer but the Toast notification is my log ;)
But i found another way that work. 

new CountDownTimer(1000*60*rand.nextInt(60)+1000*60*60, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }
    
                public void onFinish() {
                 showNotification();
                }
             }.start();